# Trying to rename "figures" to "schemes"

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing a PhD thesis in chemistry using the popular [Classicthesis template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-typographic-thesis) and I am trying to change some figures to schemes.

**Here's the issue:**

Figure 2, as an example, should be a scheme and not a figure.

I have tried--with no luck--for several hours for a solution to this.

For example:

```
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext = los ,
  name = Scheme
]{scheme}
```

This worked in a way since it changed the captions labels to "scheme"s, but when trying to add a list of schemes to the contents section, **it has the schemes incorrectly labelled as figures**. Very strange to me.

I tried also with the "**chemscheme**" package with the same result.

I have a copy of my thesis on [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/DavidKLeonard/thesis_).

Comment: Probably with `\renewcommand{figurename}{Scheme}` and `\renewcommand{listfigurename}{List of schemes}` to change the caption Figure to Scheme

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of `newfloat` answers this question. Appart from code below, see also documentation for `\PrepareListOf` there.

If you use TeXlive, get it with terminal command

```
texdoc newfloat
```

There you get the example:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
...
\usepackage{newfloat,tocloft}
\newlistof{diagram}{lod}{List of Diagrams}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name=Diagram,fileext=lod]{diagram}
% Note: Due of a bug in tocloft the file extension
% must be repeated at \DeclareFloatingEnvironment,
% otherwise you will get an empty list.
% Customize ‘List of Figures’
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure~}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2cm}
% Customize ‘List of Diagrams’
\renewcommand{\cftdiagrampresnum}{Diagram~}
\setlength{\cftdiagramnumwidth}{2cm}
...
\begin{document}
...
\listoffigures
\listofdiagrams
...
\end{document}
```